# I've written myself into a corner Where to place database specific helper methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inversion-of-control

Okay, I don't think my controller should know about sql.

I want to convert incoming null values to my action to be changed to MinValue

`var salesFrom = Model.SalesFrom ?? SqlDateTime.MinValue;`

But, if I add this line to my controller action, then my controller is turned to a SQL specific implementation.  So, I thought it belongs in  my Service....But, since it is a statement that would vary by implementation, I don't want to make it part of My `IService` because then I have to implement it for any Service I create.

Finally, I thought to add it to the DataContext, but my controller doesn't directly access the Context....

Comment: How do you generate your model? Code-first?

Comment: Introduce new interface, add this interface to any models you need. If you are creating some kind of generic controller - check if the model is an instance of that interface, if so - cast to the interface and get value form interface method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about EF but I think this is good practice.

I like to keep my model/controller completely DB agnostic.

What I would do if I was you:

1. Instead of using SQLDateTime use just **DateTime**, either in you controller/model (mvc).
2. If you have to, do the conversion later in a different layer (your DAO for instance)
   (for instance I use nHibernate and it handles that for me, I only work with DateTime)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using EF Code-First, then set a default value of `SalesFrom` property of your model class to `SqlDateTime.MinValue`. Or, would this too be SQL specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding `OnModelCreating` for your DbContext and specify DB default values for generated columns using Fluent API.